# Reading unicode from swing component and displaying it in swing component fails

Tags: swing, unicode

I am trying to display a unicode string in a table as specified in the following program.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author dell
 */
public class UnicodeExample extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /** Creates new form UnicodeExample */
    public UnicodeExample() {
        initComponents();
        setTitle("Unicode Example");
        setSize(400, 400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        jLabel1.setText("Enter :");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel1);
        jLabel1.setBounds(24, 50, 70, 20);

        jTextField1.setText("\\u00a5");
        getContentPane().add(jTextField1);
        jTextField1.setBounds(110, 50, 220, 20);

        jButton1.setText("Display Entered UniCode");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jButton1);
        jButton1.setBounds(120, 110, 160, 23);
        getContentPane().add(jLabel2);
        jLabel2.setBounds(120, 170, 150, 40);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here
        String uniCode = jTextField1.getText();

        jLabel2.setText(uniCode);
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new UnicodeExample().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

But the Unicode characters are not displaying. This is happening only when I get the value from an externel source as a parameter and set that value to the Swing control. But there is no problem if I hard code the string like `String unicode="\u00a5"`

Is there any fix to this problem ?

Comment: Was those auto generated comments necessary to clarify your problem?

Comment: See also [Need help with unicode display](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2284948) at the OTN.

Comment: @Andrew: Wow! There is an (almost) exact match of my answer there!

Answer (score 1):

Hard coding works because `\u00a5` is considered as one single unicode character in that case.

However, when getting from the `JTextField`, you are getting the STRING `"\u00a5"` which is equivalent to `"\\u00a5"` if you hard code.

To be more clear, try

`char c = '\u00a5';`

`System.out.println(c);`

Edit:

If you only insert unicode representations in the input box, this little code may help:

```
String uniCode = jTextField1.getText();

uniCode = uniCode.substring(2);        
char c = (char) Integer.parseInt(uniCode, 16);                

jLabel2.setText(c + "");
```

Do this in the `actionPerformed` method.